# How to get the children element inside a div with a same class name

Tags: javascript

i try to make a trigger button from a div children with the same class,but my code below seems not working properly, i try to make a looping at first to get the class box then try to get the children from each box, but it seems not working.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
  var x = box[i].children;
  x.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log('hello world')
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box[i].children`  is returning a collection (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children )

You need to loop over it to get each nodes.

Or better, access the node you want using `querySelector` :

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
  var button = box[i].querySelector('button');
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
     console.log('hello world')
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> try to make a looping at first to get the class box then try to get
>   the children from each box, but it seems not working.

`children` returns **List of Elements**, you need to access the first one (**button**)

```
var x = box[i].children[0];
```

**Demo**

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
  var x = box[i].children[0];
  x.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log('hello world')
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note**

- If there are multiple `button`s inside each `box`, then you need to iterate `children`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can simplify that a lot.

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) takes a CSS selector as a parameter and makes it very easy to narrow the nodelist down to just the elements you want,  e.g. the `button`'s.

Stack snippet

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".container .box button");

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log('hello world')
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Or like this, using the `btn` class

Stack snippet

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".container .btn");

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log('hello world')
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button class="btn">click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`children` method returns an array of matching elements, you have to specify to which element you want to addEventListened, even if it's one child you need to indicate `x[0].addEventListener()`

That suppose to work for any amount of children inside:

```
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
  var x = box[i].children;

  for (let i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      console.log('hello world')
    })
  }
}
```